# I already have the ndk zip, how to install it without re-downloading it in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

My internet connection is unstable, so I download the ndk zip (android-ndk-r21d-windows-x86_64.zip) from some other source, and I want to install it. What should I do?

Is it possible to let Android Studio detect the zip?

I mean, in System Settings --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools, when I choose NDK(Side by Side) and click "Apply", it automatically starts to download the zip (and probably will install it after the downloading).

Is there anyway I can tell AS that I have already prepared the zip for it, and let AS just install the zip?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip into `$SDK/ndk/$MAJOR.$MINOR.$BUILD`. For example, I have:

```
$ ls ~/Android/Sdk/ndk
18.1.5063045  19.2.5345600  20.0.5594570  21.0.5935234  21.0.6113669  21.1.6352462  21.2.6472646  21.3.6528147
$ ls ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147 
build         meta       ndk-gdb    ndk-which  NOTICE.toolchain  platforms  python-packages  shader-tools  source.properties  sysroot     wrap.sh
CHANGELOG.md  ndk-build  ndk-stack  NOTICE     package.xml       prebuilt   README.md        simpleperf    sources            toolchains
```

That's a Linux system. For Windows it's the same idea but your SDK is installed somewhere else I think.

The major/minor/build number of the build comes from the `source.properties` file in the NDK:

```
$ cat ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/source.properties
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 21.3.6528147
```